# How to obtain the selected optgroup and options in array with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we get the selected optgroup and options in an array with JavaScript or jQuery. I need to get both optgourp and option into an array, but only the selected ones.

```
<select id="release">
    <optgroup label="group1">
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="group2">
        <option>option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
var releasearr = {};
var theSelect = document.getElementById('release');
var optgroups = theSelect.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');
for (var i = 0; i < optgroups.length; i++) {
    releasearr[optgroups[i].getAttribute('label')] = [];
    var options = optgroups[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
        releasearr[optgroups[i].getAttribute('label')].push(options[j].innerHTML);
    }
}
console.log(releasearr);
```

in html search button

in javascript

```
var requestString = "?re_type="+document.getElementById('route').value+"&platform="+document.getElementById('platform').value+"&baserelease="+document.getElementById('bsrel').value+"&release="+releasearr+"&release_type="+document.getElementById('type').value+"&rpd_bit="+document.getElementById('rpd_bit').value;;
```

and passing to  `url ='/rbusnp/controller/releasecompresult.php'+requestString;`

in values i am getting releasearr is as [object object] not getting the values

i am using multiple selections for this dropdown menu. but when i select one opt group and two options it is returning only one optgroup and one option, how to get the array for multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var releasearr = {};
var theSelect = document.getElementById('release');
var optgroups = theSelect.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');
var arr = {};// object for selected options
for (var i = 0; i < optgroups.length; i++) {
    l=optgroups[i].getAttribute('label');
    releasearr[l] = [];
    var options = optgroups[i].getElementsByTagName('option');

    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
        releasearr[l].push(options[j].innerHTML);
        if(options[j].selected){ // check if options is selected
            arr[l]= [];// making array of optgroup
            arr[l].push(options[j].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
console.log(releasearr);
// selected options array
console.log(arr);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZRNM/)

Using jquery you can try this,

```
var arr= {};
$('#release option:selected').each(function(){
    arr[$(this).closest('optgroup').attr('label')] = $(this).text();
});
console.log(arr);
```

[jQuery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZRNM/1/)

**Updated** you should use **JSON.stringify()** for passing your `object` as an `string` like,

```
route=document.getElementById('route').value;
platform=document.getElementById('platform').value;
bsrel=document.getElementById('bsrel').value;
type=document.getElementById('type').value;
rpd_bit=document.getElementById('rpd_bit').value;

var requestString = "?re_type="+route+"&platform="+platform+"&baserelease="+bsrel;
requestString += "&release_type="+type+"&rpd_bit="+rpd_bit;
requestString += "&release="+JSON.stringify(releasearr);// use stringify here
```

For selecting all `option` in `selected option from optgroup` try this,

```
var arr= {};
$('#release option:selected').each(function(){
    var newArr=[];
    $(this).closest('optgroup').find('option').each(function(){
        newArr.push($(this).text());
    });
    arr[$(this).closest('optgroup').attr('label')] = newArr;
});
console.log(arr);
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZRNM/2/)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. when i alert the message it is showing [object Object]. how can i get the values? can you help

Comment: As `arr` is an `object` so it will not shown in `alert` you can check in `console only`

Comment: when i get in php the result also coming as release:[object Object]] not getting values

Comment: How you are sending `arr` in `php`? Show me your `full code`.

Comment: This is the search button
<input type="button" name="Search" onClick="getreleasedataresult()" class="button_example" value="SEARCH" />
in js file sending like this
var requestString = "?re_type="+document.getElementById('re_type').value+"&platform="+document.getElementById('platform').value+"&baserelease="+document.getElementById('baserelease').value+"&release="+releasearr+"&release_type="+document.getElementById('release_type').value+"&rpd_bit="+document.getElementById('rpd_bit').value;;
 
    url ='controller/releasecompresult.php'+requestString;

Comment: Don't copy full code in `comment`, edit your `question` and mention it in your `question`. It is not understandable here

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience in variable var requestString =  you can find releasearr word, which i am sending

Comment: You should use `JSON.stringify(releasearr)` in place of `releasearr` directly, as it is an `object`.

Comment: i updated the question, can you pass the string and send.
is it like this release="+JSON.stringify(releasearr)+" instead of
 var requestString = release="+releasearr+"

Comment: thanks, actually i am using multiple selection. if i am selecting one opt group and two options the array is returning as only one option for that optgroup, like {"group1":["option 1"]} only, i need  {"group1":["option 1","option 2"]} like

Comment: thanks for your update, the demo in jsfiddle is showing like if i select one option in gruop2 it is returning all the options in group2.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4vvR/1/ check this, it is returning all the values for one selection

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery is pretty easy:

```
var $optionSelected = $('option:selected');
var optGroup = $optionSelected.parents('optgroup');
```

Even better if you have the select element and use .find()